# Alternative to Qt for Modern Cross-Platform application?

Tags: qt, user-interface, user-experience

This questions is quite open. So let me make it a bit narrower:

I would start a CAD application project. Some traditional app that run on your PC, not some web app, but it will use some clouded database. I want this project to be open-source and I would like to have some community-driven development model.

I must confess, I am a big fan of C++/Qt.( So then why ask such a question?) Some years ago I turned to Python and I was blasted by it's ease of codding/Debugging and the productivity gain over C++. The drawback of python is the loose of efficiency, which will be needed for any CAD application.

On the other hand, the drawback of C++ is its difficulty to master and to debug some points (like memory management) which might be an issue with the community (to keep the app stable).

Here are my requirement for the GUI Framework:

- Cross-Platform
- Be native on the target platform (Don't answer java please).
- Have some class to help manage thousand of 2D sprites at time.
- Be efficient, in therm of Memory and CPU resource.
- Integrate well with web by XML/JSON other RPC.

So my final question is: Can you point me to some Language + GUI toolkit that fits those requirement but that is easier to master (in a 'python' way) than C++/Qt ? Any suggestions? Or should I go with C++/Qt?

Comment: Have you looked into Qt with QML? This lets you program mostly in JavaScript, while having the opportunity to easily create modules in C++ where execution speed is at a premium. Other than that, you could try writing Qt with Python bindings and similarly drop in C++ modules where needed.

Comment: @MagnusHoff Year, this was the first option (When I mean Qt this includes QtQuick). But sill I will not be able to by-pass C++ fully and I was wondering it there was some more consistent options (I mean only one language). I was also considering using [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/) and leave the not-interactive part to Python (like import/export, etc..)